# How to get image of country based on country code in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have country code(i.e USA). I want to get image of country.

Comment: Your question is really unclear. You haven't even specified if you have the images somewhere or are you asking for a source for country maps or to have the actual map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lot of sources, few of them:

- https://github.com/gosquared/flags
- https://github.com/hjnilsson/country-flags
- https://github.com/linssen/country-flag-icons
- https://github.com/lipis/flag-icon-css/tree/master/flags (svg)
- ....

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest approach, without using any external assets, would be to just use the Unicode flags in a label, for example this is the Unicode flag of Andorra: